# Inject filter into datasource before remote data source call

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid that I want to use a custom filter on only its first load. I am pulling from a remote datasource, so I was thinking I would bind to the `dataBinding` event, manipulate the datasource to add a filter, and send it back on its way.

I could be wrong on this, but my understanding is that `dataBinding` is an event that fires pre-datasource read, which is why I want to inject my filter there.

[Update #1:]
**I am using the ASP.NET MVC wrapper of Kendo to produce this, but I want to do the filtering via Javascript because that is how I am getting my `myCustomGridFilters` array. I have a JS grid extension class that I created that houses extra grid features. This is already instantiated for all my grids, so I would not like to manually go into each grid MVC wrapper initalization and add filters.**

For reference, here's my datasource builder in my ASP.NET MVC code:

```
// remainder of Kendo Grid wrapper
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(ViewUtilities.GetDefaultGridSettings().DefaultPageSize)
    .Read(read => read.Action("ListThreatsOverview", "Threats"))
    .ServerOperation(true)
    .Sort(sort => sort.Add("ActiveInDevices").Descending())
    .Model(model =>
    {
        model.Id(u => u.Id);
        model.Field(u => u.FileHashId).Editable(false);
        model.Field(u => u.CommonName).Editable(false);
        model.Field(u => u.ActiveInDevices).Editable(false);
        model.Field(u => u.BlockedInDevices).Editable(false);
        model.Field(u => u.SuspiciousInDevices).Editable(false);
    })
)
```

I created a JSFiddle to emulate my scenario. I know it isn't an exact replica of my code, but it is an exact replica of my of situation:

Here is my `applyCustomFilter()` js method I am applying to the `dataBinding` event:

```
function applyCustomFilter (dataSource) {
    // find custom filters
    var customFilters = myCustomGridFilters.length ? myCustomGridFilters : [];

    // if no custom filters, return
    if (customFilters.length === 0) return;

    // apply custom filter
    // get currently applied filters from the Grid.
    var currFilterObj = dataSource.filter();

    // get current set of filters, which is supposed to be array.
    // if the oject we obtained above is null/undefined, set this to an empty array
    var currentFilters = currFilterObj ? currFilterObj.filters : [];

    // loop over custom filters
    for (var i = 0; i < customFilters.length; i++) {
        var filterField = customFilters[i].field;
        var filterValue = customFilters[i].value;
        var filterOperator = customFilters[i].operator;

        // iterate over current filters array. if a filter for "filterField" is already
        // defined, remove it from the array
        // once an entry is removed, we stop looking at the rest of the array.
        if (currentFilters && currentFilters.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < currentFilters.length; i++) {
                if (currentFilters[i].field == filterField) {
                    currentFilters.splice(i, 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        currentFilters.push({ field: filterField, operator: filterOperator, value: filterValue });
    }

    // apply filters
    dataSource.filter({
        logic: "and",
        filters: currentFilters
    });

    // remove custom filters
    myCustomGridFilters.length = 0;
}
```

My working JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/crhLvq44/

I got this working, but I notice that my grid is loading data twice; once initially and second to filter the data. This is obviously not ideal.

Ultimately, my goal is to filter my grid on its first load, without having to make a separate datasource read from my remote source just to filter. How can I achieve this? Is there another event I should subscribe to?

Answer (score 2):

Just add your filter to the datasource. JSFiddle is blocked here unfortunately, so can't see your code.

**Kendo UI**

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [
        { name: "Tea", category: "Beverages" },
        { name: "Coffee", category: "Beverages" },
        { name: "Ham", category: "Food" }
    ],
    filter: {
        // leave data items which are "Food" or "Tea"
        logic: "or",
        filters: [
            { field: "category", operator: "eq", value: "Food" },
            { field: "name", operator: "eq", value: "Tea" }
        ]
    }
});
```

**Kendo MVC**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyModel>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Type);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Count);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Date);
    })
    .Filterable()
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
        .PageSizes(true)
        .ButtonCount(10))
    .DataSource(ds => ds
        .Ajax()
        .Read(r => r.Action("GetGridData", "Home", new { code = 'code' }))
        .PageSize(25)
        .Filter(f => f.Add(a => a.Type).Contains("something"))
    )
)
```

Comment: I am using the MVC rapper. So I don't have immediate access to the data sources. I apologize that my example is a little misleading.

Comment: You're not defining your datasource in the MVC code? Can you post your grid source code please?

Comment: I am defining the datasource in my MVC code. But I want to do this purely in Javascript because I have a JS class that extends the grid's functionality and this extra functionality would best fit there. I'll update my question with that code.

Comment: Added my datasource builder.

Comment: Any idea how to inject this filter in pure javascript, per the question?

Comment: @Nicholas I am using the above suggested `filter` method for customized filter in my grid. When i apply the filter, data is not getting populated in grid. i am using MVVM pattern. Any help please...